# Why isn't IIS compression recognizing my set mime types?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, gzip

I am publishing an ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 web app to a Basic Azure instance. By default, my CSS is returned gzip encoded, but my javascript is not.

To diagnose this, I have added then deployed a `web.config` to my webroot:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpCompression>
            <staticTypes>
                <clear />
            </staticTypes>
            <dynamicTypes>
                <clear />
            </dynamicTypes>
        </httpCompression>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I publish the above `web.config`, all compression stops, as expected.

I then changed the sections as follows:

```
<staticTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true" />
</staticTypes>
<dynamicTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true" />
</dynamicTypes>
```

Now everything is gzip encoded; my css, javascript, html, webfonts, svgs, etcs.

Next, I limited it to just text encoding:

```
<staticTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
</staticTypes>
<dynamicTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
</dynamicTypes>
```

Again this works as expected, gzip encoding my css (`text/css`) and my html (both `text/html` and `text/html; charset=utf-8`) but nothing else.

Here's what I don't understand. The following changes have no effect:

```
<staticTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
</staticTypes>
<dynamicTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
</dynamicTypes>
```

I have checked and double checked that my javascript is indeed being returned as `application/javascript`. For good measure, I have also included the uft-8 variation.

Obviously, my `web.config` is being respected in some fashion because I can turn it off completely. Obviously, IIS is capable of compressing javascript and more because I can turn it on completely. What am I missing in my configuration that makes me unable to set only specific mime types to be compressed?

---

**Edit:**

I tried the following, adding stars to the mime type, which is now working:

```
<staticTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
</staticTypes>
<dynamicTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
</dynamicTypes>
```

Apparently there is some trailing string causing the mime types to not match without the star at the end, but I'm not sure what it is. It's not coming through on the response. Does anyone know what this mystery string could be from?

Answer (score 1):

try setting `staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency = 'True'`

This is part of the httpCompression node from the documentation:

> If True, disables the behavior that a static file is compressed only if it is hit a certain number of times within a time period.

There are several other settings that control when static compression is turned on or off as well.

from: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression

Comment: I have hit the content enough to trigger compression in all cases above. Additionally, this doesn't explain the compression when using `'*/*'`.

Comment: I have added additional information to the question.